# ClickOnce is publishing the wrong app.config

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, app-config, publish

I have a wpf clickonce application that uses multiple app.configs based on configuration. When I build it outputs the correct app.config, but when I publish it uses the wrong app.config.

Here is my setup:

- App.config - dummy empty config file.
- App.Debug.config - debugging config
- App.Test.config - test config
- App.UAT.config - UAT
- App.Prod.config - production

I have an "AfterCompile" task in my project settings that applies the correct config file based on the environment configuration and this works great. But when I use VS2012 publish wizard it uses the dummy config file regardless of the configuration setting.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution that does not involve manually copy/pasting/modifying any of the files after build or after publish as this is part of an automation process.

Comment: I had the same issue and already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58811775/196526

Answer (score 0):

Try using a BeforeCompile script instead. I've experienced the same thing and the App.config file needs to be updated prior to compilation.

Something like the following in a Pre-build event command line should do it for you.

```
  IF "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Development" (
  COPY "$(ProjectDir)App.Development.config" "$(ProjectDir)App.config"
  )
```

Comment: Tried this, it isn't going to work because its replacing a source file. If the file is readonly (because it isn't checked out of TFS) it will fail. My output files are all correct, so this is telling me that the publish command isn't using the output files generated from the build to publish.

Comment: From my experiences, ClickOnce uses the App.config located within the project directory. I can see TFS would cause you a problem here if you're using something like SVN. Is it possible to make App.config not an SVN-controlled file? In your case it is blank, and shouldn't need to be under source control. (I'm a git/hg user and have never used SVN so I don't know for sure)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other posts in this thread, I got mine to work. I have my config files in a project folder called Config and the files have the project configuration name in them. sample file name: App.Debug.Config
So this worked for me. It was put into the .csproj file.

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\Config\App.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)App.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```