# how to make azure devops release pipeline click once

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, exe, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a simple executable, that I have build and unittested in a build pipeline.
now I want to install it on some test machines and run some tests on the app, before releasing it to production. (eventually I hope to automate the tests with specflow, but that is the next step)

So basically I have an helloworld.exe build, that I want to be installed from a pipeline to at test agent computer.

I think clickonce is the optimal option, but am unsure how to set it up on azure devops. (we use a server on premises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msbuild has `Publish` target to build and publish the ClickOnce application. It will generate the `setup.exe` you want. Please check document: [Create and build a basic ClickOnce application with MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2019#create-and-build-a-basic-clickonce-application-with-msbuild). In release pipeline you can use msbuild task or Visual Studio Task with `Publish` target(`/t:Publish` as argument).

Then you'll get one `app.publish` folder where the files you want exist there:

[image]

This folder can be used for your further deployment.

Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811775/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-with-azure-devops-pipeline-on-different-e) you can refer to .

In addition, azure devops Marketplace provides some extension: [ClickOnce Packager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mansellan.clickonce), [ClickOnceMore DevOps Pipeline Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RedSkySoftware.clickoncemore-build-task).